# How to use a SQLite data base properly?

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

please suggest me solution for this code. It does not work. The application goes back after I pressed submit button. It can not store data

```
public class UserContract  {
//if you need multi tabless user inner classes to represent each table inn class

public  static abstract class NewUserinfo implements BaseColumns
{
    public static final String USER_NAME="user_name"; //right side represent column name
    public static final String USER_MOB="user_mob";
    public static final String USER_EMAIL="user_email";

    public static final String TABLE_NAME="user_info";

}
```

}

---

```
public class UserDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static final String DATABASE_NAME="USERINFO.DB";
private static final int database_version=1;
private static final String create_query=
        "CREATE TABLE "+ UserContract.NewUserinfo.TABLE_NAME + " ("+ UserContract.NewUserinfo.USER_NAME+" TEXT, "+
        UserContract.NewUserinfo.USER_MOB+" TEXT,"+ UserContract.NewUserinfo.USER_EMAIL+" TEXT);";


public UserDbHelper(Context context)
{
    super(context,DATABASE_NAME,null,database_version);
    Log.e("database operation ","database created /opend");

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(create_query);
        Log.e("database operation","table created");
}
public void addinformation(String name, String mob, String email, SQLiteDatabase db)
{
    ContentValues contentValues=new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(UserContract.NewUserinfo.USER_NAME,name);
    contentValues.put(UserContract.NewUserinfo.USER_MOB,mob);
    contentValues.put(UserContract.NewUserinfo.USER_EMAIL,email);
    db.insert(UserContract.NewUserinfo.TABLE_NAME,null,contentValues);
    Log.e("database operation","one row insert");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {

}
}
```

---

```
public class NewContactActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
UserDbHelper userDbHelper;
SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;
EditText editText,editText1,editText2;
Context context;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_contact);
    editText=findViewById(R.id.contect_name);
    editText1=findViewById(R.id.mob_number);
    editText2=findViewById(R.id.email);
}

public void addcontact(View view)
{
    String name= editText.getText().toString();
    String number=editText1.getText().toString();
    String email=editText2.getText().toString();
    userDbHelper=new UserDbHelper(context);
    sqLiteDatabase=userDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    userDbHelper.addinformation(name,number,email,sqLiteDatabase);
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "data saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


}
}
```

Comment: Have you any stackerror to show us?

Comment: Does it showing any error in console If showing please add it

Comment: redirect to main activity after showing an error message

Comment: show your logcat

Comment: this come red line in logcat

Comment: 02-08 16:22:06.453 1994-1994/com.example.abbas.sqlitedatabase E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable', referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.hasOverlappingRendering

Comment: Next time add the error log with you code in coding format with proper edit.

Comment: @Syed please declare the EditText properly in onCreate method

Answer (score 0):

you require a primary key in one of the variables. say it like this.

```
String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(" + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + TITLE + " TEXT," + PRINT_NAME + " TEXT," + MRP + " TEXT," + QTY + " TEXT, " + IMAGE + " BLOB, " + WEIGHT + " TEXT " + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
}
```

The Overall Code Should Look Like...

```
public class SQLiteHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Club100database";
private static final String TABLE_NAME = "myclub100cart";
private static final String KEY_ID = "cart_id";
private static final String TITLE = "title";
private static final String PRINT_NAME = "print_name";
private static final String MRP = "mrp";
private static final String QTY = "qty";
private static final String IMAGE = "image";
private static final String WEIGHT = "weight";


public SQLiteHandler(Context context) {

    super(context,DATABASE_NAME,null,DATABASE_VERSION);
}


@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(" + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + TITLE + " TEXT," + PRINT_NAME + " TEXT," + MRP + " TEXT," + QTY + " TEXT, " + IMAGE + " BLOB, " + WEIGHT + " TEXT " + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {
    db.execSQL(" DROP TABLE " + TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}
}
```

Comment: first see the comment line then answer

Comment: It is "answering" the title ... but did you read the question ? PS: where is it said that it is required to have a PK in a table ?

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned error:

> 02-08 16:22:06.453 1994-1994/com.example.abbas.sqlitedatabase
>   E/dalvikvm: Could not find class
>   'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable', referenced from method
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.hasOverlappingRendering

Its not the issue of DataBase , its issue of Drawable Resource

Look into this

[Could not find RippleDrawable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31474297/could-not-find-rippledrawable)

[Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable', Could not execute method for android:onClick, Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42378473/could-not-find-class-android-graphics-drawable-rippledrawable-could-not-execu?rq=1)